# Why my kitten bites my face and nose in the morning?

Tags: cats

My kitten is 6 month old and in morning time she wakes up then starts to walk and make a prrr sound as usually she does that sound when she doesn't find her self busy... 
Then she comes to bed smells my face then starts to lick my eyes if I am not showing the sign that I am awake she will go back on the floor and the jumps on my face with a hard bite to my nose between my eyes... Most of the times the first thing what she does when I just open my eyes she starts constantly jump on  my biting all face and she bites really strong that after those attacks bite marks bleeding... She never does that to my boyfriend and I find it very strange... Do I do something wrong? I never hurt her she has no reason to hate me...